# HERE MAPS load very slowly on physical devices

Tags: flutter, here-api, heremaps-android-sdk, heremaps-ios-sdk, heremap-navigation

I'm working with HERE MAPS navigate sdk on my flutter project. The maps load and search super fast on the simulators but when I run using a physical device (iPhone or Android) it loads super slow. Literally takes minutes to search or load tiles.

I have tried debug and non-debug mode, even tried running using an apk but the speeds are abysmal. Other things I have tried are VPNs, mobile data and different Wifis.

Could anyone from here maps please assist?

here_sdk 4.9.3
flutter 2.5.3

Comment: For a first time start it's always a bit slower. Thereafter, it's usually faster. But do you have some more exact measures how long it takes for a cold start? And under which conditions you are testing? Is the data connection fast enough? Maybe running a speed tester could help to verify the issue is not because of a bad connection while you are on the go.

Comment: Agreed on the comment provided by @Datasun ! Could you please provide the above information so that we could check this with the product team.